# SEO implications of loading pages (with e.g. ajax) on a single page

Tags: seo, ajax, site-structure

I have an e-commerce site that needs 3 clicks (and page loads) to get to the actual product. This was done with the intention to have more goolgle-bot scannable pages, and therefore better ranking for having more content.

However, performance after several years asks for a change.

**My questions is:**

What are the SEO downsides of leaving the last 2 pages out of the menu (hiding them from robots), and loading all the options dynamically from *1 page*? Think: a lot of variations on one product *instead of* many product pages.

Here is the current structure:
1. Category (Mattresses) (first click from the home page) 
2. Type of mattress (brand, style, material, etc)
3. Depth of mattress (they are unique because of various types of layers)
4. Finally on the product

Comment: Here is a related article about combining product variations for SEO: https://www.merkleinc.com/blog/ecommerce-seo-product-variations-colors-and-sizes

Comment: When you say it takes 3 clicks to get to a product, can you walk us through those three clicks?  Is that home page, then category page, then product page?     Then later you talk about combining product variations into one page, but I'm not sure how that squares with how many clicks from the home page to get to a product.